# TeXLive: meaning of sys_bin, sys_man and sys_info when using --portable

Tags: installing, texlive

I'm trying to understand what the `sys_bin`, `sys_man` and `sys_info` options for TeXLive should point to.

At the moment, I'm installing everything on a pen drive using the `--portable` installer option, and would like to leave nothing in the "host" computer, even when updating my installation.

I'm just guessing here, but shouldn't `sys_bin` point to something along the lines of `/media/disk/bin/i386-linux`? any ideas as to how to make this less "mountpoint-dependent"?

The TeXLive documentation is moot on the matter and I've had no luck searching the "normal" channels.

**PS:** I understand this may well be off-topic here, I tried to tag it as much as possible, but found nothing more "uninviting" than `{texlive}` and `{installing}`... please do close if off-topic nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options `sys_bin`, `sys_man` and `sys_info` refer to the standard system directories for binaries, man and info pages, where [symlinks](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#option) should be created.  These symlinks are not created unless you specifically enable that in the installer or call `tlmgr path add`, something you don't want for a potable setup.  In other words, don't worry about this.